# Удаление миграции в Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Смотрю видеоуроки по Laravel. Он там себе по несколько раз создает и удаляет миграцию. Я создавал,  потом удалял, а при попытке опять создать миграцию с таким же именем, вылезает ошибка. В чем может быть дело?
P.S. На скрине название миграции первое что пришло в голову для примера.

[image: Migr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда ты создаешь миграции они создаются не только в папочке миграций, а и в базе данных. И если ты потом удаляешь просто файл то в следующий раз при запуске миграций оно не найдет этот файл. 
Запусти php artisan migrate:refresh
Это выполняет откат всех миграций, а затем запускает команду migrate.

Comment: Я миграцию не применял, только создал. Потом удаляю, пытаюсь создать снова - ошибка как на скрине.

Comment: composer dump-autoload

Comment: Да, действительно помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Сам не пробовал, но говорят этот метод работает:

Сначала

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Затем

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: Да, помогает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще так, удаляет все таблицы и заново создает

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

А еще

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

Удаляет самую последнею созданную таблицу